# Web Application

Tags: angular, typescript

I met this problem on my web project. What needs to be improved?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IMineral } from '../Mineral/IMineral.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MineralWorldService {




  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
   }
    getAllMinerals(): Observable<IMineral[]>
    {
     return this.http.get('data/minerals.json').pipe( map(data=>
      {
           const mineralsArray: Array<IMineral> =[];
           for( const id in data )
           {
             if(data.hasOwnProperty(id))
             {
               mineralsArray.push(data[id]);
             }

           }
           return mineralsArray;
      }
          )
    );
    }
}
```

Element implicitly has an `any` type because expression of type `string` can't be used to index type `Object`.
No index signature with a parameter of type `string` was found on type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

if
`this.http.get('data/minerals.json')` fetch a simple `IMineral[]` array which contains only object an not nested array object you don't need  `for( const id in data )` loop just do like this :

```
 getAllMinerals(): Observable<IMineral[]>
    {
     return this.http.get('data/minerals.json').pipe( map(data=>
      {
           const mineralsArray: Array<IMineral> =[];
          
             if(data.hasOwnProperty(Id))
             {
               mineralsArray.push(data);
             }

          
           return mineralsArray;
      }
          )
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find name 'id'.
Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IMineral'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'IMineral': Id, Name, Formula, Price, Quantity

These are the new errors. If it helps, this is the IMineralinterface.ts file

```
export interface IMineral{
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Formula: string;
  Price: number;
  Quantity: number;
}
```

And this is the other ts file for list of components.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MineralWorldService } from 'src/app/services/mineral-world.service';
import { IMineral } from '../IMineral.interface';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-mineral-list',
 templateUrl: './mineral-list.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./mineral-list.component.css']
})
export class MineralListComponent implements OnInit {

 minerals!: Array<IMineral>;



 constructor(private mineralworldService: MineralWorldService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void
 {
   this.mineralworldService.getAllMinerals().subscribe(
     (       data: any)=>{
       this.minerals=data;
       console.log(data);
     }, error =>{
       console.log('httperror:');
       console.log(error);
     }
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: it's Id and not id